# Spring boot exception - due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, spring-rest

I am trying to do a simple spring boot application. 
Getting an exception while running as jar.

```
00:48:47.580 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:137)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:536)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151)
    at au.com.itgeeks.spring.cloud.config.SpringCloudConfigurationServer.main(SpringCloudConfigurationServer.java:12)
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:189)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:162)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:134)
    ... 8 common frames omitted
```

All fine when I use command

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

but I am getting an error while using

```
java -jar target/spring-cloud-config-server-1.0.jar
```

my pom.xml pasted here.

```
    <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud-dependencies.version>Brixton.SR7</spring-cloud-dependencies.version>
    <spring-cloud-starter-config.version>1.2.2.RELEASE</spring-cloud-starter-config.version>
    <spring-cloud-config-server.version>1.2.2.RELEASE</spring-cloud-config-server.version>
    <spring-boot-starter-web.version>1.5.1.RELEASE</spring-boot-starter-web.version>
    <spring-boot-maven-plugin.version>1.5.1.RELEASE</spring-boot-maven-plugin.version>
    <docker.image.prefix>springio</docker.image.prefix>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-cloud-dependencies.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-cloud-starter-config.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot-starter-web.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot-starter-web.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot-starter-web.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>au.com.itgeeks.spring.cloud.config.SpringCloudConfigurationServer</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
            <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <imageName>${docker.image.prefix}/${project.artifactId}</imageName>
                <dockerDirectory>src/main/docker</dockerDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <targetPath>/</targetPath>
                        <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                        <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Please note - I am using -  maven-shade-plugin in my pom.xml

**Answer is**

No need use shade plugin.

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Or you can do as maven command as well.
many thanks to first comment.

Comment: Don't use the `maven-shade-plugin`... The `spring-boot-maven-plugin` takes care of creating an executable jar.

Comment: thanks, buddy! your answer spark me to the solution. Please see edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

use below dependencies :

```
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
        <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

and you need to use some annotation on main class like :

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(ScheduledTasks.class, args);
    }
}
```